# Ignoring differences in brightness with ImageMagick compare tool

Tags: image, compare, imagemagick, brightness

I'm using `compare` to find if something has changed between two photos. It generally works well, except when the room suddenly becomes a bit darker or brighter. So I'm wondering - is it possible to ignore the difference in brightness when running `compare`?

So far I'm using the command below:

```
compare -fuzz 15% -metric ae /path/to/image1.jpg /path/to/image2.jpg /path/to/diff.png
```

For example, for this set of images, I would get approximately 5% difference, while I would like to bring it below 1% or even less if possible.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you use `NCC` rather than `AE` as the metric, the images are normalised first and you will see a 07.% difference rather than the 4.6% you currently see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could normalize the two images, then compare those:

```
convert VaoZF.jpg -normalize image1.ppm
convert whgkn.jpg -normalize image2.ppm
compare -fuzz 15% -metric ae image1.ppm image2.ppm diff.png
```

You can get the difference metric with a single command and without making any temporary files:

```
magick \( VaoZF.jpg -normalize \) \( whgkn.jpg -normalize \) \
      -fuzz 15% -metric ae -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
```

If you are on Windows, use "(" and ")" instead of "\(" and "\)" and use a "^" instead of a "\" for suppressing the line break, and replace "%" with "%%".